# Adding a function pointer within a struct to print

Tags: c, function, struct

What would be the proper way to do the following in C?

```
typedef struct Book {
    char* title;
    unsigned int year;
    void // print ??;
} Book;
```

```
void print_book(Book *book)
{
    printf("{\n\ttitle: \"%s\",\n\tyear: %d\n}\n", book->title, book->year);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Book romeo = {
        .title="Rome & Juliet",
        .year=2000
    };
    print_book(&romeo); // how can I do romeo.print() instead?
}
```

What would be the correct way to define the struct member `print` to point to the `print_book` function?

Comment: `romeo.print()` can't work in C, only in C++. In C the best you can do would require `romeo.print(&romeo)`, which isn't really better than `print_book(&romeo)`. And storing the function pointer would require extra space in every instance of the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to declare it would be:

```
typedef struct Book {
    char* title;
    unsigned int year;
    void (*func)(struct Book *book);
} Book;
```

I had to use `struct Book` instead of `Book` because the `Book` type has not yet been defined.

A better way to do it is:

```
typedef struct Book Book;
struct Book {
    char* title;
    unsigned int year;
    void (*func)(Book *book);
};
```

This creates the `typedef` before the structure definition, so the `typedef` name can then be used inside the structure.

To call it, you can do:

```
Book romeo;
romeo.func = print_book;
(*romeo.func)(&romeo);
```

In this context, you can optionally apply the `&` operator to `print_book`, e.g. `romeo.func = &print_book;`.  The two are equivalent.

Note that I've called the function pointer `func`, but you can of course use any name you like (e.g. `print`, as in your post).

Comment: what does `(*func)` do? I've never seen that before in C.

Comment: That's the traditional way to declare a function pointer (as opposed to an actual function definition).

Comment: @carl.hiass I suggest you read about **Function Pointers**.

Comment: @TomKarzes I see -- thank you. How would I then call the `print` member on the `romeo` object?

Comment: @gsamaras sure can you provide a link with a good tutorial/documentation or something?

Comment: @carl.hiass If you have `Book book;` and you set `book.func`, then you could call it as `(*book.func)(&book);` for example.  The syntax has loosened up a bit in terms of including the `*`, but I like the call to match the declaration.  That way it's clear that it's a function pointer.

Comment: @carl.hiass that is a plethora of options out there ;) Here is one I had used some years ago: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: You'd need to call `romeo.print(&romeo)` or given a book pointer,  `bookp->print(bookp)`.  It isn't as canvas C++ where the `this` pointer is provided automatically.

Comment: @TomKarzes could you please show an example of the `func` function and how it would be called? I keep getting a seg fault when trying to access the `func` (which I've renamed from print).

Comment: @carl.hiass Sorry for the name change, I hadn't realize that you had intended it to be called `print`, but you can use any name you like.  The example call from my previous comment should work.  I just added it to the answer - refresh the page and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't, because your `print()` function does not know about the `Book` containing it (or a pointer to it). It would have to be a function which takes a `Book` or `const Book *` as a parameter.

Also, it is not a good idea to mix-up the logic for printing a book with the fundamental definition of a book. Maybe in some other context, books are printed differently? They're still books. In most (?) programming languages supporting objects with methods, simple abstract objects don't include methods for printing themselves - that is done using stand-alone functions or other constructs.